# Remote Desktop in Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

I am running a windows 10 home edition and there is no Remote Desktop option in it. I want to remote in to my Windows 10 machine from linux but cant do that. So I installed RDP wrapper to enable this feature. But it says that it is not supported. Is there any way that i can enable remote desktop without RDP wrapper? I have Remmina installed on my linux. Any one please help me with the issue.

Comment: You could try RealVNC?

Comment: But RealVNC is paid I cant afford paid software .Thank you for your reply

Comment: Home has Remote Assistance the exact same thing as Remote Desktop. Difference Home Server has to invite Home client. With RD Clients can attempt to connect without an invitation.

Comment: The realVNC site states: `Our free version of VNC Connect is available for personal, non-commercial use for up to 5 devices`. Also, there are plenty alternatives if you google "freeware rdp software linux windows" like TigerVNC and TightVNC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest not to force Windows Home to enable Remote Desktop, especially
as it's prohibited by your user license of Windows.

For desktop sharing you could use instead a third-party
[VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)
based product, many of whom are free.

Here are some products (in no special order):

- [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/)
  free for personal use
- [TigerVNC](https://tigervnc.org/)
  free and open-source
- [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/)
  freemium
- [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://alternativeto.net/software/chrome-remote-desktop/about/)
  free and browser-based
- [AnyDesk](https://alternativeto.net/software/anydesk/about/)
  free for personal use
- [Remotely](https://remotely.one/)

Comment: I use TigerVNC, and it works perfectly, you only need to add windows FW rule to allow it to accept connection .

Answer (score 1):

According to [The Windows Club - How to use Windows 10 Remote Desktop in Windows Home (RDP)](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-use-windows-10-remote-desktop-in-windows-home-rdp)
even when you have the wrapper installed, it will still claim RDP is unsupported… but it should work when accessed remotely.

> Post installation, if you go to Settings > System > Remote Desktop, it will still say that remote desktop is not available. Though, other computers can connect with the Windows Home PC.

Comment: But it is not working i have tried many versions of rdp wrapper and it is saying unsupported and when i tried to remote in its not working.Thank you for your reply

Comment: You need to clarify in your original question precisely what you've tried & what the results were.

Comment: I have only tried RDP wapper its installation went succesfully and But when i tried to connect my windows from linux its not working then i checked and opened RDP check and it tell that my system is not supported and then I Reinstalled it but there is same problem And my question is not about rdp warapper. I want to know if any other method exist other than rdp wrapper

Comment: See my comments above.

Comment: Please don't add pertinent information in comments. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1684241/edit) your question to include the new information.